# How to load log4j2.xml configuration files from another module

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I'm trying to create log4j2 project as a lib module

My goal is every App project(A,B,C,...) can import log4j2.xml configuration from log4j2 module (using same log4j2.xml for remove duplicate code) but it nothing happens log4j2 is not loading.

[image]

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{black} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{1.}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable" />
        </Console>

        <File name="JSONLogfileAppender" fileName="target/logfile.json">
            <JSONLayout compact="true" eventEol="true"/>
            <BurstFilter level="INFO" rate="2" maxBurst="10"/>
        </File>
        <Async name="AsyncAppender" bufferSize="80">
            <AppenderRef ref="JSONLogfileAppender"/>
        </Async>

        <Async name="AsyncAppenderRedis" bufferSize="80">
            <AppenderRef ref="REDIS"/>
        </Async>

        <RedisAppender name="REDIS"
                       key="log4j2-messages"
                       host="xx"
                       port="yy">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%level %msg"/>
            <RedisConnectionPoolConfig testWhileIdle="true"
                                       minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
                                       timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
                                       numTestsPerEvictionRun="-1"/>
            <RedisThrottlerConfig bufferSize="500"
                                  batchSize="100"
                                  flushPeriodMillis="1000"
                                  maxEventCountPerSecond="100"
                                  maxByteCountPerSecond="4194304"/>
        </RedisAppender>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncAppenderRedis" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncAppender" />
        </Root>

        <!-- LOG "net.mypackage" at TRACE level -->
        <Logger name="net.mypackage" level="trace"></Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework.cache" level="trace">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the technique described in item #1 of the [Automatic Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) section of the log4j2 manual?

Comment: @Panupong Kongarn: were you able to solve it with the help of this comment? Not sure how log4j.configurationFile is supposed to work

Comment: I give up to use log4j2, I use logback instead that it use slf4j as default and It can make lib module